# .delay to function Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have a function

```
function hello() {
    alert("hello world!");
}
```

and I want to call it, I just do `hello()`, but if I want to do a delay? Should I do:

```
$.delay(3000).hello();
```

Would this work?:

```
$.fn.hello = function() {
    alert("hello world!");
}
$.delay(...).hello()
```

Comment: Why can't you use setTimeout?

Comment: @IgorShults just a different way of using it, nothing but that.

Comment: I believe .delay() is for use only with animations.  Such as: slideup().delay().slidedown()

Comment: @JuanRocamonde [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) won't work, it's just for jQuery effects/animations.  setTimeout is really what would typically be used here.

Comment: @IgorSgults would the update work?

Answer (score 2):

Is this homework, or some code golf problem? Because `setTimeout` is really the ideal function in this case, and [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) won't work because it's just for jQuery effects/animations.

I suppose you could use `setInterval` and clear after the first invocation.  Something like:

```
var interval;

function hello() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("hello world!");
}

interval = setInterval(hello, 3000);
```

If you can't alter the `hello()` function or use it elsewhere, you can create a wrapper function for the `setInterval` call, and use that instead.

Comment: I like your answer, which demostrates that things can be reached many ways. The point was about doing it different, but I wasn't waiting for something like this.

Comment: @Igor I think it's worth emphasising the point that `$.delay()` _only_ affects the jQuery animation queue. Otherwise, perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

You can always just add to the queue

```
$.fn.hello = function() {
    alert("hello world!");
    return this;
}

$(document).delay(3000).queue(function() {
    $(this).hello().dequeue();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBQ4u/2/)

The reason it only works on animations, is because those are added to the FX queue automagically, but anything can be queued and dequeued in jQuery, you can even create your own custom queues that will work with `delay()`

For a custom queue you can do something like this

```
$({}).delay(3000, 'custom').queue('custom', function( next ) {
    $(this).hello();
}).dequeue('custom');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBQ4u/3/)

This is a little different, it's showing us that we can use an empty jQuery object as the holder and not just an element, and the second argument in `delay()` is used to pass in the name of the queue, which we then attach and dequeue a little differently.

We're not really using the `next` argument as there is nothing more in the queue to call, but it's an argument that you call to go the next step, as in you'd call `next()` inside the function to proceed.

Comment: I think if you're going to queue something custom, you might want to show targeting the custom queue. Using the default `.delay()` isn't good because animations/effects from anywhere affect this

Comment: @Ian - Agreed, added an example that shows a custom queue and a few other things as well.